# isomorphism of graph definition

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

In [Douglas West's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130144002) of graph theory, this is how isomorphism of graphs is defined. Please note that graphs need not be simple.

> An isomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a bijection $f$ that maps $V(G)$ to $V(H)$
>   and $E(G)$ to $E(H)$ such that each edge of $G$ with end points $u$ and $v$ is
>   mapped to an edge with endpoints $f(u)$ and $f(v)$.

Though I get the idea what author seems to say, however I feel the definition is ambiguous in sense that $f: G \to H$. Hence  $f(u)$, $f(v)$ does not make any sense.

**Query 1** : Please tell me how right am I in judging the above definition.

**Query 2** : Here below I propose my own definition of isomorphism which seems to me a little bit more clear. Please tell me if it is right or not.

> Graphs $G$ and $H$ are said to be isomorphic iff there exists bijection
>   $f,g$ as defined $f : V(G) \to V(H)$ and  $g : E(G) \to E(H)$ such that
>   whenever  $g(e) = e'$  then $u$ and $v$ are end points of $e$ iff $f(u)$ and $f(v)$ are
>   end points of $e'$.

Edit: The definition of graph in the book is like this:

> A graph $G$ is a triple consisting of a vertex set $V(G)$ and an edge set
>   $E(G)$ and a relation that associates with each edge two vertices not
>   necessarily distinct called end points.

**Query 3**: Upon reading Bondy Murthy's graph theory book's definiton, I think that in above graph definiton won't it be precise to use "function" and not "relation"?

Comment: The way it's defined doesn't mean that $f$ is a bijection from $G$ to $H$, it means $f$ is a bijection from $V(G) \cup E(G)$ to $V(H) \cup E(H)$, which is perfectly valid. It also depends on how the graph is defined in the text, in the one I used a graph was defined as a triple $(V, E, \delta)$ and an isomorphism is defined as a pair of bijections.

Comment: Well, you are right IF IT MEANS -" f is a bijection from ..." . But look at above definition. It simply states that - "An isomorphism from G to H IS A BIJECTION f that maps ..." . He bluntly says that very isomorphism is a bijection named f . It should say- " There exists isomorphism if there is a bijection f that ... " . As far as how he defines a general graph here , I have updated the question. I still think his way of defining it is wrong .  As far as your definiton , I checked and found it is same as in Bondy's book and I agree with that isomorphism definiton completely.

Comment: "An isomorphism from G to H is a bijection f that..." is just shorthand for "If there exists a bijection f that maps ... then we call f an 'Isomorphism from G to H'". There's a suble difference between "An isomorphism from G to H is a bijection f..." and "An isomorphism is a bijection f from G to H...".

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism **is** a bijection (either a bijection $f:V(G) \cup E(G) \to V(H) \cup E(H)$ that sends vertices to vertices and edges to edges, or a pair of bijections $f:V(G) \to V(H)$, $g:E(G) \to E(H)$; these are equivalent). This is correct.  There may be more than one isomorphism from $G \to H$. The two graphs are said to be isomorphic if and only if there exists an isomorphism.  You are giving a definition of what it means for two graphs to be isomorphic, and the book is giving the definition of an isomorphism.

Their definition for the "relation" is indeed a bit strange.  The way they word it, it does sound more like a function taking an edge and returning a set of either one or two vertices (depending on whether the edge is a loop or not).

But really it is better to consider it as a relation between $E(G)$ and $V(G)$.  We call this relation "incidence" and it can go both ways.  In this case the relation is not a function, because each edge (except loops) is related to two vertices, and each vertex may be related to several edges.